# Remove comma in jQuery Flot

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, flot

I'm working on a project and I need to use some charts.
For this project I've chosen to use Flot: http://code.google.com/p/flot/

The problem is, how can I change the x-axis values?
From a database I receive the data and parse it to the flot. No problem.

But sometimes I only receive 2 values from the database and the x-axis seems weird.

Instead of: 0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, ... 
I only want 0, 1, 2, 3, ...

Some goes for the y-axis

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the following will set your axis labels:

```
xaxis: { min: 0, ticks: [[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2], [...]], max: 3 }
```

Search on the [docs page](http://flot.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/API.txt) for 'Customizing the axes'.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could solve it also with this here:

xaxis: {
        tickDecimals: 0
    }

See orginal post: [Put only integers in x and y axis of bar and line graphs - Flot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12908222/put-only-integers-in-x-and-y-axis-of-bar-and-line-graphs-flot)