# Put only integers in x and y axis of bar and line graphs - Flot

Tags: jquery, flot

In Flot.js, bar graphs and line graphs have numbers as the coordinates in the x and y axis by default.

[image: Line graph sample]

How can you make the coordinates such that the numbers are only integers or at least only the integers are visible?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Check out the `minTickSize` option from the [documentation](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md):

> Alternatively, you can specify that you just don't want ticks at a
>   size less than a specific tick size with "minTickSize".

So in your graph options, you would specify it like this:

```
$.plot($('#placeholder'),data,{
   //your options,
   xaxis: {
      minTickSize: 1
   }
});
```

See it working here:  http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/g2CTz/

Comment: I ran into a similar problem and tried a solution similar to yours. It didn't work. I set the minTickSize to 1 and saw ticks of 0, 2.5, 5, 7.5, 10, etc.

Comment: @mikez302 - that's surprising!  I guess you should write up a question and I'll take a look :)

Comment: this didn't work for me too, but Michael Cordingley 's solution worked. I'm using jquery.flot.js v0.8.1

Comment: This works just for not showing other than .0's, but still it shows .0's.

Comment: I am trying this on bar graph but it is not workign for me. I have tried `yaxes` and `yaxis`

Answer (score 62):

Looks like more recent versions of Flotr use a different option to control this since the original answer:

```
    xaxis: {
        tickDecimals: 0
    }
```

Just supply an integer with the number of decimals to show.

NB: This is for Flotr2.

Comment: This is the correct answer, this should have been accepted.
Flot version: Flot 0.8.3

Comment: At the time that the other answer was accepted, it was the correct answer. I think the library ended up changing shortly thereafter, rendering the answer no longer correct.

Comment: what is the correct answer? this does not work on bar graph?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show integers on the x or y-axis try this

```
yaxis: {
    tickSize: 1,
    tickDecimals: 0
},
```